# How to fix intermittent PHP Fatal error: Unknown: Cannot find save handler '/var/lib/php/session'

Tags: php, apache, session, redis, centos7

Very intermittently and rarely my Centos7 httpd 2.4.41 and php 5.6.40 server will half load a page. The PHP loads, but the CSS and JS includes get the error 'Connection Reset' in chrome and dump this error into the php error log.

### PHP Fatal error: Unknown: Cannot find save handler '/var/lib/php/session'

I have checked permissions on the session files, and the server has plenty of space, the fact that it works most of the time makes my scratch my head.

I've tried switching to memcached but same issue.

Can anyone share any light on whats causing this error?

Or perhaps a way to stacktrace the httpd PID after the fatal error?

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Are you doing something silly like calling `exec('php foo.php');` in your code somewhere? CLI invocations rarely ever use the same php.ini, you'll likely get default values, like for session handling, and other assorted horrors.

Comment: No sir, just running Symfony PHP framework.

Comment: We're experiencing this today. Using CodeIgniter 3.1.11. session.save_path = /phpsession and has proper permissions. Also set perms on /var/lib/php/session just in case. Seems random.

Answer (score 0):

This issue might be related to your session save path. If you are not precious on where to save the sessions.

edit your php.ini and change the following

we are using the /tmp directory here.

session.save_path = /tmp

more information can be found here

http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path

Comment: I have read this before on other forums, it does not help me, same error. Anyways it says on the php website

Warning
If you leave this set to a world-readable directory, such as /tmp (the default), other users on the server may be able to hijack sessions by getting the list of files in that directory.